# Linux kernel slab usage growing every second

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

Memory in Linux is filled with kernel slab memory, which is not cleared in any way.
The only thing that helps is restarting the host, but that's a crutch option.
This is slabtop:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 28034545 / 29319770 (95.6%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 465171 / 465171 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 125 / 174 (71.8%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 1806743.68K / 1902193.54K (95.0%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.06K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
29040064 27807394  95%    0.06K 453751       64   1815004K vmap_area
 53312  37622  70%    0.57K   3808       14     30464K radix_tree_node
 36992  23604  63%    0.03K    289      128      1156K lsm_inode_cache
 28098  22426  79%    0.19K   1338       21      5352K dentry
 25888  25881  99%    0.12K    809       32      3236K kernfs_node_cache
 14388  13465  93%    0.62K   1199       12      9592K inode_cache
  9216   8996  97%    0.02K     36      256       144K kmalloc-16
  7917   4467  56%    1.16K    609       13      9744K ext4_inode_cache
  7488   6275  83%    0.06K    117       64       468K kmalloc-64
  7098   6734  94%    0.15K    273       26      1092K vm_area_struct
  6688   5298  79%    0.25K    418       16      1672K filp
  6464   5623  86%    0.12K    202       32       808K kmalloc-128
  6400   5822  90%    0.03K     50      128       200K kmalloc-32
  5632   5592  99%    0.01K     11      512        44K kmalloc-8
  5440   4354  80%    0.02K     32      170       128K lsm_file_cache
  5312   4646  87%    0.06K     83       64       332K anon_vma_chain
  4526   4526 100%    0.05K     62       73       248K ftrace_event_field
  4053   4053 100%    0.70K    177       23      2832K proc_inode_cache
  3297   2098  63%    0.19K    157       21       628K kmalloc-192
  2574   2515  97%    0.10K     66       39       264K anon_vma
  2535   1976  77%    0.10K     65       39       260K buffer_head
  2272   1575  69%    0.50K    142       16      1136K kmalloc-512
  2184   2180  99%    0.09K     52       42       208K trace_event_file
  1806   1341  74%    0.09K     43       42       172K kmalloc-96
  1696   1598  94%    0.25K    106       16       424K kmalloc-256
  1472    418  28%    0.06K     23       64        92K kmalloc-rcl-64
  1376    802  58%    0.25K     86       16       344K maple_node
  1280   1077  84%    0.12K     40       32       160K pid
  1232   1134  92%    1.00K     77       16      1232K kmalloc-1k
```